# Configuration of Swagger...Problem with Login

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, swagger-ui

In my Spring Boot project I created the SwaggerConfig class like this:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.springbootinfluxdb.api.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

And the application.properties is:

```
### DATABASE ###
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

server.port: 8088
```

When I try to access the Swagger, through the address "localhost: 8088 / swagger-ui.html # /" the following login interface appears:

[image]

But I don't have the login credentials.
Perhaps, I could use a password that appears in the eclipse output console logs every time they run the project.

How can I solve the problem??
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your security config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-ui.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: It always asks me for login credentials.
my class now extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I added the configure method as you suggested ... but it always asks me for credentials

Comment: upload info of your pom.xml file and class security config to help me know core problem